# Проблемы с доступом к локальному серверу

Tags: windows, storybook

У меня запускается локальный сервер storybook. При старте выдает вот такое. По localhost все работает, по ip тоже. Но при попытке зайти на ip с другого устройства (Внутри wifi сети), доступ получить не удается. Раньше все работало, но позже я обновил антивирус с ESET32 на PRO32, а также установил RadminVPN. (это как раз его ip выдает, вместо ip машины)

Думаю, один из двух закрыл доступ внутри сети, но как найти причину не понимаю. У антивируса ужасный интрефейс, а радмину доступ к файрволу закрыл антивирус. Кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Как мне заново открыть доступ к ip внутри wifi сети?

```
 Storybook 6.5.7 for React started                                                      │
│   29 s for manager and 46 s for preview                                                  │
│                                                                                          │
│    Local:            http://localhost:4001/                                              │
│    On your network:  http://26.145.101.256:4001/                                         │
│                                                                                          │
│   A new version (6.5.16) is available!                                                   │
│                                                                                          │
│   Upgrade now: npx storybook@latest upgrade                                              │
│                                                                                          │
│   Read full changelog: https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/CHANGELOG.md
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел причину там, где даже не искал. Оказалось, что моя сеть была публичной, а антивирус автоматом настраивает файрвол так, чтобы никто из публичной сети не мог получить доступ к моей машине (что логично). Сменил режим работы с "Публичный" на "Домашний" и все сразу заработало.